# Jquery Validate. Validate on "keyup" and hide form when password is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I want to implement an uncommon functionality and I thought jquery validate plugin would be the best way to do it (if you suggest and answer without the plugin, it will be welcomed as well). I want to hide the form as soon as the user enters the correct word on the input field.
I tried this:

```
  $("#beta_form").validate({
    onsubmit: false,
    onkeyup: true,
    rules: {
        beta_password: "1789"
    },
    success: function(){
        $("#beta_form").addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
```

So, as soon as the user enters "1789" (without having to hit submit), the form is supposed to hide.

I get this error:

```
 TypeError: settings[eventType].call is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done it without using validate plugin

**HTML :**

```
<form id="formid">
    <input type="text" id="password" ></input>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

**Jquery :**

```
$("#password").keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val() ==='1789'){
        $("#formid").hide();
    }
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/unpb5r1v/6/)

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: @Sparky OP also said '(if you suggest and answer without the plugin, it will be welcomed as well)' and also for this simply task i dont thing he need to load complete jquery-validate plugin am i right in my point?...

Comment: You are correct that he also asked for answer without using the plugin, so I've removed my downvote.  However, I think an answer that fixes the broken code he presented it would be more helpful to others than going into a new direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid setting...

```
onkeyup: true
```

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onkeyup),

> **onkeyup**
>
> *Type: Boolean or Function()*
>
> Validate elements on `keyup`. As long as the field is not marked as
>   invalid, nothing happens. Otherwise, all rules are checked on each `keyup`
>   event. Set to `false` to disable. Set to a Function to decide for
>   yourself when to run validation.
>
> **A boolean `true` is not a valid value**.

In other words, validation on every `keyup` event is already the *default* behavior so you must not set this option to `true`.  You can only set this option to `false` (to disable) or to a function (to over-ride).  Leave the option out to keep the default behavior.